# Distance between two group of values in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, graph, distance

I have a very basic question which in theory is easy to do (with fewer points and a lot of manual labour in ArcGIS), but I am not able to start at all with the coding to solve this problem (also I am new to complicated python coding).

I have 2 variables 'Root zone' aka `RTZ` and 'Tree cover' aka `TC` both are an array of 250x186 values (which are basically grids with each grid having a specific value). The values in `TC` varies from 0 to 100. Each grid size is 0.25 degrees (might be helpful in understanding the distance).

My problem is "I want to calculate the distance of each `TC` value ranging between 50-100 (so each value of TC value greater than 50 at each `lat` and `lon`) from the points where nearest `TC` ranges between 0-30 (less than 30)."

Just take into consideration that we are not looking at the np.nan part of the `TC`. So the white part in `TC` is also white in `RZS`.
[image]

What I want to do is create a 2-dimensional scatter plot with X-axis denoting the 'distance of 50-100 `TC` from 0-30 values', Y-axis denoting '`RZS` of those 50-100 `TC` points'. The above figure might make things more clear.

I hope I could have provided any code for this, but I am not to even able to start on the distance thing. 
Please provide any suggestion on how should I proceed with this.

Let's consider an example:
If you look at the x: 70 and y:70, one can see a lot of points with values from 0-30 of the tree cover all across the dataset. But I only want the distance from the nearest value to my point which falls between 0-30.

Comment: Do you want to cross-correlate *all* 50-100 points with *all* 0-30 points when calculating the distances? Because that manes each single 50-100 point will have a large number of values, not a single value.

Comment: @9769953 Sorry for the doubt. It's the nearest value between 0-30. This is also mentioned in the last line of 3rd paragraph. I have added an example, which might be helpful.

Comment: For a given point with a value between 50 and 100, you want to know the distance to the *nearest* point that has a value between 0 and 30? Is that correct? And then of course, for each of the points with a value between 50 and 100.

Comment: @9769953......Yes that is correct.

Comment: Just in case these data, or something very similar, is somewhere publicly available, I'd love to have a pointer to it, so that I can make my answer (and example) more representative, and in general, better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code might work, with random example data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Create some completely random data, and include an area of NaNs as well
rzs = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(250, 168))
tc = np.random.lognormal(3.0, size=(250, 168))
tc = np.clip(tc, 0, 100)
rzs[60:80,:] = np.nan
tc[60:80,:] = np.nan

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.imshow(rzs)
plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.imshow(tc)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Now do the real work:

```
# Select the indices of the low- and high-valued points
# This will results in warnings here because of NaNs;
# the NaNs should be filtered out in the indices, since they will 
# compare to False in all the comparisons, and thus not be 
# indexed by 'low' and 'high'
low = (tc >= 0) & (tc <= 30)
high = (tc >= 50) & (tc <= 100)
# Get the coordinates for the low- and high-valued points,
# combine and transpose them to be in the correct format
y, x = np.where(low)
low_coords = np.array([x, y]).T
y, x = np.where(high)
high_coords = np.array([x, y]).T

# We now calculate the distances between *all* low-valued points, and *all* high-valued points.
# This calculation scales as O^2, as does the memory cost (of the output), 
# so be wary when using it with large input sizes.
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist
distances = cdist(low_coords, high_coords)

# Now find the minimum distance along the axis of the high-valued coords, 
# which here is the second axis.
# Since we also want to find values corresponding to those minimum distances, 
# we should use the `argmin` function instead of a normal `min` function.
indices = distances.argmin(axis=1)
mindistances = distances[np.arange(distances.shape[0]), indices]
minrzs = rzs.flatten()[indices]

plt.scatter(mindistances, minrzs)
```

[image]

The resulting plot looks a bit weird, since there are rather discrete distances because of the grid (1, sqrt(1^1+1^1), 2, sqrt(1^1+2^2), sqrt(2^2+2^2), 3, sqrt(1^1+3^2), ...); this is because both TC values are randomly distributed, and thus low values may end up directly adjacent to high values (and because we're looking for minimum distances, most plotted points are for these cases). The vertical distribution is because the RZS values were uniformly distributed between 0 and 100.
This is simply a result of the input example data, which is not too representative of the real data.

Comment: Sadly, I have no easy way of uploading the notebook that I created this in, which would make for a slightly nicer read than the current combination of code, comments and figures.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I tried this and it works fine. The only issue with this is I am unable to visualize which pixel belongs to which class. Can we add tree cover class to the plot in different colours? Like TC between 50-60 in one colour and so on. I am not able to do it cumulatively for all dataset in one go.